# New Mac Apple ID won't accept payment details

Tags: mac-appstore

Having just unwrapped my new Mac and set up Apple ID, I tried to download the updates waiting for me. I get a message saying "This Apple ID has not been used yet in the App Store. Please review your account information". When I try to do this, it will not allow me to proceed without credit card details, just to download free updates (!). OK, fine i will probably buy the odd App or two, but it will not accept my card details because I have a UK bank card with a Spanish billing address. I am from the UK but have lived in Spain for some years and never had problems using this card. I am stuck in this endless loop I cannot escape from and unable to update my new computer. i am beginning to wish i had bought that PC after all - can anybody help me?!

Answer (score 1):

Ring them.
Or rather, get them to ring you - which they will, in English, to Spain

Start at https://getsupport.apple.com

I've had to do a similar thing in the past when setting up my folk's new Mac last year, British accounts, English speakers, Spanish address.

They are incredibly helpful & patient. You really won't regret having bought a Mac.